# Converting linked list from raw pointers to smart pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I need to convert a C implementation of a doubly linked list that uses raw pointers, to an implementation using smart pointers instead.

I have some small experience with smart pointers.

Im working on converting the insertFirst() function to get my bearings and understand how this will come together.

```
struct node {
  int data;
  int key;

  std::shared_ptr<node> next;
  std::weak_ptr<node> prev;
};

void insertFirst(int key, int data){

  //create a link
  //struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  std::shared_ptr<node> link = (std::shared_ptr<node>) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  link->key = key;
  link->data = data;

  if(isEmpty()){
    //make it the last link
    last = link;
  }else {
    //update first prev link
    head->prev = link;
  }

  //point it to old first link
  link->next = head;

  //point first to new first link
  head = link;
}
```

Im having trouble with this line:

`struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

I thought doing like so:

`std::shared_ptr<node> link = (std::shared_ptr<node>) malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

was all I would need. But i am less familiar with C and what exactly is happening and why this is not allowed.

I get the error:

`no matching conversion for C-style cast from 'void *' to 'std::shared_ptr<node>'`

Can anyone offer some tips and explanation?

Comment: You can't use `malloc` for `node` because it won't construct it properly you should use `std::make_shared` (or at least `new`). Btw do you really need *shared* pointers?

Comment: You do not need shared pointers, but since the introduction of C++11, it is more professional to use `shared_ptr` `weak_ptr` and `make_shared` instead of using `new` and `delete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When constructing `C++` class instances, you must use `new` and `delete`, instead of `malloc` and `free`. `malloc` and `free` are C library functions, that know absolutely nothing about C++ class constructors, destructors, and everything else that goes with what a C++ class is all about.

The shown code is attempting to construct an instance of the `node` class by using `malloc`. that won't work. `new` must be used to construct it:

```
std::shared_ptr<node> link = new node;
```

That's even shorter and neater, than the C-style concoction comprised of `malloc`, and an ugly cast.

You mentioned that you are in the process of converting C code to C++. A mandatory part of that conversion is to replace all `malloc` and `free` calls with `new` and `delete`. This is not optional, this is required for proper C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I found a good article I need to read to get a further understanding on use shared pointers. I believe the goal here is to eliminate any calls to `new` and `delete` and instead perform all allocation and deallocation with `shared_ptr` and `make_shared`